# Hide and Close Forms

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I have three forms. Let's call them A, B, C for now.
Form A is a main application, you can open a form B, and C from it. I want to add an option, that if you click a button in form B, it will close it, and hide the rest of the Forms.
I was trying with something like that, but it gives me an error

```
        private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
            Form.A.Hide();
            Form.C.Hide();
        }
```

Comment: So closing Form B will make the application somewhat unusable because all the other forms are hidden?

Comment: *it gives me an error* - why do people think it's a great idea to say this, but then when seeking help on it, they don't mention the exact error message?

Comment: What is the error it gave to you?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the form instances visible to each other (You cant just guess at syntax).

In each form do

```
public partial class  FormX : Form{
     ....
     public static FormX Instance = null; <<<=== add this
     ....
     public FormX(){
         InitializeComponent();
         Instance = this;                 <<<== and this
     } 
      ...
 }
```

For each of FormA, FormB and FormC.

now you can do

```
     FormA.Instance.Close();
     FormC.Instance.Hide();
```

or whatever you need